# How to access adb shell on remote machine?

Tags: android, automation, adb

I need to programmatically start an android application on a specified remote emulator. I think adb shell should be the right tool, but it seems the adb shell could be only accessed locally. Could anyone tell me how to get my job done?

Comment: you have to enable adb debugging  port on remote device. I enabled my device through setprop service.adb.port 5555. This cmmand may be wrong. Plz google yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you accessing the machine remotely?

When you access this machine remotely you either need to use Remote Desktop in Windows or Putty in Windows or SSH in Linux/UNIX and a phone needs to be connected in order to run ADB with it.

If you have that figured out, you can accomplish what you would like:

Open a Command Prompt/Terminal:

For Example:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
```

View Example:

```
http://www.android.pk/blog/general/launch-app-through-adb-shell/
```

Please let me know if this helps!